# How to pass QtString to a function that accepts string as data type

Tags: qt

I am trying to use QT for a project to check consistency of an XML file.

I have a function called `Check_XML_Consistency()`, which takes a string as input and returns a string as output. I have a problem when using it with QT, when I cast the data in the text file to string and cast it back to qtstring to show it, the program gives me an error.

I checked and verified that the problem is with spaces. When I remove all spaces from my text editor the program runs well.

Any suggestions for a QT beginner?

Here is my code:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    QString text =ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText();

    string x=text.toUtf8().constData();
    string Result=Check_XML_Consistency(x);
    QString str = QString::fromUtf8(Result);
    ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(str);

}
```

Comment: You say "the program gives me an error". Can you provide the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

If `Check_XML_Consistency()` actually takes a *std::string* and not a *C-string* then you would want

```
...
string x = text.toStdString();
string Result = Check_XML_Consistency(x);
QString str = QString::fromStdString(Result);
...
```

Comment: Still not working

Comment: the Check_XML_Consistency is a c++ Function

Comment: What is the signature of the `Check_XML_Consistency` function?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no compile time error. And if it takes and returns std::string then use `QString::toStdString()` to convert QString to std::string, and for vice versa use `QString::fromStdString(const std::string &str)`.
Because we don't know what the error actually is, may be your function has some issues, but you can use third party XML manipulators or Qt's XML classes.